# given starting source and ending destination, find all paths from database of points in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider that I have a table of points, each point has 2 coordinates. For example:

```
Source       |       Destination 
1            |       2
2            |       3
3            |       7
5            |       7
9            |       12
```

I'd like to write a query in SQL that gives me the following:

1. All the paths that these points make,starting from a given (specific) source and a given destination. Each path must have connected points, as in the next point's source coordinate is the same as the previous point's destination point.
2. a path can't be cyclic.

For example, in the table above, running the query with source=1 and destination=7 should return only 1 path:

1. (1,2) (2,3) (3,7)

I'd be happy for an answer :)

EDIT:
I asked the question that's marked a duplicate and it's not the same question, because:
this question asks about a SPECIFIC start and a SPECIFIC end while the "duplicate" asks about ALL possibly connected paths.

Comment: Is this SQL Server PostgreSQL?

Comment: yes it  SQL Server PostgreSQL